# Can't hear audio from speech from system voice with headphones but can hear music?

Tags: itunes, mac, audio, headphones

I'm trying to set up listening to selected text in Accessibility > Speech. I have headphones on, and when I play iTunes I can hear perfectly. When I click play on the Speech window in Accessibility, I can't hear anything. When I take the headphones out, it works? How do I get it to work with headphones?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! :) It may be useful to add the version of macOS you're using. You can do this by [editing](https://apple.stackexchange.com/posts/305507/edit) your question.